# How to find a surface if we know the normal vectors?

Tags: surfaces

I have the positions of 3D particles at each z-section [each color represents a particle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EcqV.png). The lateral projection of the data looks approximately like this image[The top end of these particles form a curved surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55McS.jpg)
I want to generate a surface locally normal to the particle direction (calculated as $(dx/dz,dy/dz)$. Is there anyway to do this?

I tried inverse gradient but it didn’t work.
Thank you,

Comment: Can you describe more in details what the figure you posted represents?

Comment: Each three point can give one surface. you have to have coordinates of all points to find the equation of each surface.

Comment: Hi, I am more inclined towards using the particle direction rather than particle positions.